# How is the integral over real symmetric positive definite matrices defined?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

I often encounter integrals over the space of real symmetric positive definite matrices,
$$
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbf{X>0}} f(\mathbf{X}) d\mathbf{X},
\end{equation}
$$
where $f$ is a scalar function. One example is the [multivariate gamma function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.3#i).

In basic terms, how are these integrals defined?

Comment: @Masacroso, thank you for the comment. But what does this mean practically? To me it is not straightforward, how I would integrate over the relevant subset.

Comment: @光復香港時代革命FreeHongKong, thanks for the link. But in case of integrating over symmetric p.d. matrices it is not as easy as just integrating component-wise, right? The possible values $\mathbf{X}_{i,j}$ can take depend on the other entries in the matrix, or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. They're different. I've not seen it before. The reference mentioned in [Numerical integration for functions of symmetric matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106773/numerical-integration-for-functions-of-symmetric-matrices) should provide explicit examples for integration over symmetric positive definite matrices.

Comment: @光復香港時代革命FreeHongKong, thanks for the reference. I tried to incorporate it in an answer below.

Comment: The space of $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices is "the same" as $\mathbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$. The space of positive-definite matrices is just an open subset of it. And integration over open subsets of a Euclidean space is easy :)

(For example, for $n=1$ the space of symmetric matrices is simply $\mathbb R$ and when we add the positive-definiteness condition, we restrict it to $\mathbb R^+$. A good exercise is to think about $n=2$).

Answer (score 1):

From the reference in @光復香港時代革命FreeHongKong's comment it seems that

$$
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbf{X>0}} f(\mathbf{X}) d\mathbf{X} 
   = \int_{\mathbf{\mathbf{L}^+}} f(\mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}') 
     J_{\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'}(\mathbf{L}) \, d\mathbf{L} 
   = \int_{\mathbf{\mathbf{L}^+}} f(\mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}') 
     2^p \prod_{i=1}^{p} \mathbf{L}_{ii}^{p-i+1} \, d\mathbf{L}
\end{equation},
$$
where $\mathbf{L}^+$ denotes the space of all lower triangular matrices with positive diagonal elements and $J_{\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'}(\mathbf{L})=2^p \prod_{i=1}^{p} \mathbf{L}_{ii}^{p-i+1}$ is the Jacobian of the transformation $\mathbf{L} \rightarrow \mathbf{L} \mathbf{L}'$.

Now, integrating over $\mathbf{L}^+$ boils down to a multiple integral over the lower triangluar elements, which for the elements below the main diagonal runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and for the elements on the main diagonal runs from $0$ to $\infty$.